# CutyCapt Segmentation Fault

Tags: ubuntu, screenshot, segmentation-fault

I m using cutycapt software to create a screenshot of a site. It works fine, but for some sites I get **segmentation fault** error. For example, following command will cause the issue:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" cutycapt --url="http://www.wahm.com/forum/" --delay=2000 --out=1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segmentation faults during normal operation are bugs in the software. Report the bug to the developer. There's nothing else you can do about it.